# How to start Activity in my adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-adapter

How can I start activity in adapter? I use this method in my adapter:

```
post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context,asabani_cat.class));
    }
});
```

But this worked just for fragment of my app, when I called this code in Activity App suddenly crashed!

Another question that I have, is it the good way to start activity in adapter?

my logcat:

> 11-27 21:25:25.086 22237-22237/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 11-27 21:25:25.086 22237-22237/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException 11-27 21:25:25.086 22237-22237/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime: at com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam.adapter_common$7.onClick(adapter_common.java:266) 11-27 21:25:25.086 22237-22237/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime: at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4377) 11-27 21:25:25.086 22237-22237/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime: at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18044) 11-27 21:25:25.086 22237-22237/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 11-27 21:25:25.086 22237-22237/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 11-27 21:25:25.086 22237-22237/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 11-27 21:25:25.086 22237-22237/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306) 11-27 21:25:25.086 22237-22237/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-27 21:25:25.086 22237-22237/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 11-27 21:25:25.086 22237-22237/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 11-27 21:25:25.086 22237-22237/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 11-27 21:25:25.086 22237-22237/com.katibehpayam.mahdi.katibehpayam E/AndroidRuntime: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Please post your Log (Exceptions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try:

```
post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(),asabani_cat.class));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should post the error from the Logcat so we can help you further. However from what you've shown I can find nothing inherently wrong with your code. Make sure your context is set correctly. Furthermore if you are already in an Activity you do **not** need to say

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context,asabani_cat.class));
```

you can simply say

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, asabani_cat.class));
```

If you are not in an Activity then you need to pass the context like so

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
```

Then inside your adapter set your context like this:

```
MyAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

**EDIT**

Your logcat shows a null pointer exception is the cause of your crash. Can you please post the code from adapter_common.java at line 266? Thanks

Comment: i used this code in my adapter and this can't work in it :-(

Comment: is your adapter inside an Activity or in its own class file?

Comment: Also please add the logcat code in your question, not as an answer so others can see it easily

Comment: see my edit, I need to see what code is on line 266 in adapter_common.java

Comment: this is 266 line : context.startActivity(new Intent(context,asabani_cat.class));

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin, on your view:

```
class YourClass: ArrayAdapter<Feature>(), View.OnClickListener{

   override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {

       var yourView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false)
       yourView .setOnClickListener(){
           onClick(convertView)
    }
  }

 override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    val intent = Intent(mContext, SeckondActivity::class.java)
    mContext.startActivity(intent)
}
```

}